# MS Test results freeze GUI

Tags: windows, unit-testing, testing, ide, freeze

Some of my unit tests have long debug trace output, say hundreds of lines recording conversations between a client and a web service, so when I view result details, the GUI of Visual Studio freeze, and the symptom is that right-clicking for context menu results in black rectangle.  And the other Windows applications freeze as well. Closing the Test Result Details window won't help, and I have to close VS IDE to unfreeze Windows.

Have you seen such symptom? Can you provide a solution or workaround?

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Try killing ctfmon.exe. That application has been responsible for more VS headaches and UI freezes than anything else I've encountered.

Comment: thanks for your hint. However, ctfmon.exe is not running on my Win7 machine.